# Error with C++ Constructors

Tags: c++, object, constructor, reference, instantiation

**1.** If I instantiate objects like this, no error occurs.

```
class A {};

int main () {
    A a = A ();
    A &b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

**2.** If I instantiate object this way, compiler reports `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'A (__cdecl \*)(void)' to 'A &'` when `a`'s reference is copied to `b`.

```
class A {
};

int main () {
    A a();
    A &b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

**3.** But if I add a constructor with parameters and pass in some argument(s) to this ctor during instantiation in the second way, there is no error!

```
class A {
public:
    A (int a) {}
};

int main () {
    A a(5);
    A &b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the compiler thinks that `A a();` is a function returning `A` called `a`, that takes no parameters.

`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'A (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'A &` says that the compiler doesn't know how to convert a function returning `A` taking no parameters `(void)` to a reference of type `A`.

Comment: Thank you @millsj, that pretty much explains it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create object "a" of class "A" and you want call the constructor without parameters you mustn't write "A a();", but simply "A a;". I used to make that mistake from time to time as well. The standard constructor is automatically called.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake while typing. Don't write A a (). You have to leave the brakets away. Sorry again, my fault.